# Show full post using direct route, how to pass values to the template based on route name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a simple post React project where I have a list of posts **Posts.js** and a full post template **FullPost.js**. In **Posts.js**, I pass the **slug** and **id** so that I can render the url.

For example, **'food'** has a list of posts. I click on a post and it passes the **'slug: carrots'** and **'id: 2'** to **'food/carrots'**. This **'id'** is passed so it can find the correct pathname to my carrot post in my database i.e. **'mydatabase.com/food/posts/2/'**

This works well, however when I refresh the page the **'slug'** and **'id'** that got passed to the **FullPost component** earlier **disappears**. Additionally, I would like to be able to access the URL directly, for example, if I type in **'www.mywebsite.com/food/carrots'** it would load my carrot post. Currently my **FullPost** does not load when I refresh or when I go to the post's URL directly. Is there a way to load the post from these other entry points?

Below is my code:

My database:

```
posts:    
    0:
        slug: "beans"
        id: 1
    1:
        slug: "milk"
        id: 2
    2:
        slug: "carrots"
        id: 3
```

Posts.js: A list of posts.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from '../../../axiosPosts';
import Aux from '../../../hoc/Aux/Aux';
import classes from './Posts.css';
import Post from '../../../components/Post/Post';

class Posts extends Component {

    state = {
        posts: []
    }

    componentDidMount () {
        this.getData(this.props.pathname, this.props.filter);
    }

    getData(pathname, filter) {
        axios.get(pathname + '.json')
            .then(response => {
                const post = response.data.filter(({category}) => category === filter);

                const updatedPosts = post.map(post => {
                    return {
                         ...post
                    }
                });

                this.setState({
                    posts: updatedPosts
                });          
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    postSelectedHandler = ( slug, id ) => {
         const URL = `${this.props.match.url}/${slug}`;
         this.props.history.push({pathname: URL, id: id });
     }
     render () {
         let posts = <p style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Whoops! Something went wrong.</p>;
        if(!this.state.error) {
            posts = this.state.posts.map(post => {
                return (
                    <Post 
                        key={post.id}
                        title={post.slug}
                        clicked={() => this.postSelectedHandler( post.slug, post.id )} />
                );
            });
        };
        return (
            <Aux>
                <div className={classes.PostList}>{posts}</div>
            </Aux>
        )
    }
}
export default Posts;
```

FullPost.js (Actual Post)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from '../../../axiosPosts';
import classes from './FullPost.css';

class FullPost extends Component {

state = {
    loadedPost: null,
}

componentDidMount () {
    const { location: {id} } = this.props;
    this.loadData(id);
}

loadData(id) {
    if ( id ) {
        if ( !this.state.loadedPost || (this.state.loadedPost && this.state.loadedPost.id !== +id) ) {
            axios.get( '/food/posts/' + (id - 1) + '.json' )
                .then( response => {
                    this.setState( { loadedPost: response.data, locationId: id } );
                });
            }
        }
    }
    render () {
        let post = <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Please select a Post!</p>;
        const { location: {id} } = this.props;
        if ( id ) {
            post = <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Loading...!</p>;
        }
        if ( this.state.loadedPost ) {
            post = (
                <div className={classes.FullPost}>
                    <h1 className={classes.Title}>{this.state.loadedPost.title}</h1>
                </div>
            );
        }
        return post;
    }
}

export default FullPost;
```

App.js: Main js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import classes from './App.css';
import Layout from './hoc/Layout/Layout';
import Posts from './pages/Posts/Posts';
import FullPost from './pages/FullPost/FullPost';


class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log('[App.js] Inside Constructor', props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={classes.App}>
                <Layout>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/food/" exact component={Posts} />
                        <Route path="/food/:slug" exact component={FullPost} />
                        <Route render={() => <h1>Whoops! What you're looking for isn't here anymore.</h1>} />
                    </Switch>
                </Layout>
            </div>
         );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like [React Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router).

In a nutshell your issue is that there is no URL matching logic in your code (everything would work the same even if you didn't change the URL at all).

Comment: I see, you mean if I had used 'id', instead of 'slug'? I've added my app.js file to this question, which shows the usage of 'react-router-dom', would that be sufficient?